# One-line Elideable QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to make a Qlabel that will only fill available space in Qt (really in PyQt but the same principle applies). It's meant to display a (sometimes really long) file path, and as I currently have it the length of the label makes the minimum size of that part of the window way too large.

I want to make the label's text be reduced to the maximum possible length *without exceeding the minimum width due to the other widgets in the panel*. I have found the QFontMetrics::elideText() method, which can effectively clip the text in the way I want, but I still can't figure out how to get the pixel width without the label affecting the size of the panel.

My hackjob thought process is to set the Qlabel's sizes to zero by overriding size/minimumsize/maximumsize, measure the remaining space allotted, and then set text to that. However, I don't know how to get that remaining space, and I feel like there should be a better way.

My layout for reference:

[image: my layout - label in question is the comically long path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QLabel is a pretty neat widget: it *seems* very simple, but it's not.

The size and displaying aspects are very important: since it's able to display formatted text, it can even have some [layout issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues).

Since your requirement is to keep the label as small as possible (but while keeping its content displayed if possible), the most important requirement is to implement the `sizeHint` (and `minimumSizeHint()`) functions, since the layout of the parent widget will consider that when resizing its contents.

A possible solution is based on two aspects:

- provide a basic [minimum] size hint that doesn't consider the whole contents
- override the painting by eliding text whenever the available space is not enough

The following code obviously does **NOT** consider rich text formatting, including different paragraph alignment, word wrapping, etc.

This is an example showing a subclassed QLabel trying to display the following path:
`'/tmp/test_dir/some_long_path/some_subdir/imagepath/'`

[image: screenshot of elided label]

Consider that you could even actually use a basic QWidget instead. In the following code I'm considering the QFrame subclassing abilities which also include adding proper margins and borders, depending on the style and the `frameShape` or `frameShadow` properties.

```
class ElideLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    _elideMode = QtCore.Qt.ElideMiddle

    def elideMode(self):
        return self._elideMode

    def setElideMode(self, mode):
        if self._elideMode != mode and mode != QtCore.Qt.ElideNone:
            self._elideMode = mode
            self.updateGeometry()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.text()).size()
        l, t, r, b = self.getContentsMargins()
        margin = self.margin() * 2
        return QtCore.QSize(
            min(100, hint.width()) + l + r + margin, 
            min(self.fontMetrics().height(), hint.height()) + t + b + margin
        )

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionFrame()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        self.style().drawControl(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ShapedFrame, opt, qp, self)
        l, t, r, b = self.getContentsMargins()
        margin = self.margin()
        try:
            # since Qt >= 5.11
            m = self.fontMetrics().horizontalAdvance('x') / 2 - margin
        except:
            m = self.fontMetrics().width('x') / 2 - margin
        r = self.contentsRect().adjusted(
            margin + m,  margin, -(margin + m), -margin)
        qp.drawText(r, self.alignment(), 
            self.fontMetrics().elidedText(
                self.text(), self.elideMode(), r.width()))
```

Comment: This works great! I had to change some things because I'm in qt6, but this works perfectly. The most important secret was overriding minimumsizehint() as well (didn't know that was a thing), but the rendering looks great as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `paintEvent()` and achieve it in the following way:

```
class QElidedLabel(QLabel):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        textDoc = QTextDocument()
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        elided = metrics.elidedText(self.text(), Qt.ElideRight, self.width() - 10)
        textDoc.setPlainText(elided)
        textDoc.drawContents(painter)
```

This will draw the Elided Label automatically and you won't have to change your code anywhere else. Also you can set the size policy of `QLabel` to `MinimumExpanding` to make sure your `QLabel` takes the maximum available space. This way the `self.width()` returns the current maximum width. You can take a look at documentation for the working of `QTextDocument()` and `QFontMetrics()`. Also, `self.width() - 10` just makes sure that `'...'` in the elided label is not hidden, you can remove `- 10` and just use `self.width()`  if `..` visible for you after removing it as well.

Comment: Note: 1. the 10 value is arbitrary, as it depends on the current fontMetrics. 2. `text()` will always return the "raw" text, so trying to use a QTextDocument with `setHtml` is pointless, as it won't be consistent with the actual parsed html text (which could also be invalid if the elision "cuts" away tags).

Comment: This almost works great, but I can't resize to smaller than the text width [I'm using a qsplitter on the greater window] and the bottom of the text is cut off, even if I set the minimum height

Comment: @musicamante This was derived from my original code for a Text formatted QLabel which required, so thats the reason for `setHtml`. Here `setPlainText()` can be used. I can share the code for the formatted elided QLabel as well if necessary.

Comment: @minerharry you can use `textDoc.setPlainText()`, that may fix the issue. I have edited the code as well now. If it is still a isuue then you can also set the alignment to Top which may be able to fix it.

Comment: @YogeshBhandari I understand that, but the OP has different requirements that should be considered. While using QTextDocument is not a bad idea to begin with (QLabel does it, in fact, but that's an assumption since `text` could be in any format), and the OP is probably not going to require a formatted text, using `setHtml` is still wrong conceptually, since it's based on the `text` property, which doesn't provide any hint about the formatting since it returns the QTextDocument raw text (unless `Qt.mightBeRichText()` is going to be used to check for that), so the elision could still be wrong.

Comment: @YogeshBhandari don't get me wrong: your implementation is not "wrong" per se (my answer actually ignores that aspect at all, but I *specified* that). What I'm saying is that that aspect should be taken into account and should also be considered in the explanation. Since text elision of QFontMetrics doesn't consider QTextDocument formatting (nor it can, and for good reasons), using a QTextDocument is almost pointless. The simpler QFontMetrics `boundingRect()` is formally enough, because it's almost impossible to consider layouting aspects.

Comment: @musicamante Okay, I understand your perspective. I will take this into account when I post in the future.